# How do I store a JPG in Android, for later use?

Tags: android

I have an app that is "skinned" at launch. The idea being that it looks to the server and loads several graphics for display.  It then moves through a sequence of Activities. I don't want it to have to keep visiting the server for the art, however, every time it comes to Activity 1.  I want to be able to store the images until such time as the user manually clicks a "refresh art" button.

I have every part of this worked out (the downloading, display, storing bits of other data in SharedPreferences), but I can't figure out where to save these images. They don't need to be available to any other application, I just want to have access to them from one running of the app to the next, until the user manually refreshes them.

TIA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could cache them on the sdcard.

Comment: I know... I was thinking of that, and storing the paths in SharedPrefs, but that seemed kind of kludgy. I was imagining there's a more Androidy way of doing it. Not to mention that in this scenario, I still have to load them from the SDCard every time I get back to Activity 1. I guess I was hoping there's some way to load them into some static memory space at initial launch and keep them there... maybe that's asking too much :)

Comment: That would take up way too much memory - storing them on the sdcard is pretty standard. Only access them as you need them...

Comment: I don't think it would take up much memory at all... we're talking about a grand total of 100k worth of art. But I see your point. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

you can save your images as static Bitmap objects in an extension of Application class, and referencing it from manifest:

---

manifest.xml

YourApp.java
public class YourApp extends Application{
    public static BitMap[] myImages = new BitMap[someSize];

---

YourActivity.java

in somewhere..

YourApp.myImages[position]= myImage;

---

I think it can work.

But use this only if your images are small and few ones.

The right thing is to save them in the disk, I prefer to use the internal storage against the sd card, take a look of this http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesInternal